# Where did the Sanskrit language originate from?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sanskrit, indo-aryan

Where did the Sanskrit language originate from?

Did it originate from Persia or Greece?

Where did Sanskrit evolve into a classic language: India or Persia or Greece?

- [Origin of Sanskrit](https://scroll.in/article/737715/fact-check-india-wasnt-the-first-place-sanskrit-was-recorded-it-was-syria)

The above article says that Sanskrit originated from Syria. But, I need an authentic reference, not a news article.

Comment: Short answer: India.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius, long answer [**not in India**](https://scroll.in/article/737715/fact-check-india-wasnt-the-first-place-sanskrit-was-recorded-it-was-syria).

Comment: That link seems to answer your question pretty well.

Comment: @user366312 right, knew it came from there, but didn't realise that it diverged from proto-indo-iranian so early on, thank you.

Comment: @TKR, but, I need an authentic source, not a media article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The oldest antecessor of Sanskrit is found in Anatolia (today's Turkey and Northern Iraq) in the [Mitanni kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitanni). While the language used in correspondence and archives was Hurrian (not obviously related to Indo-Aryan), personal names of the Mitanni ruling class, the names of gods and godesses, and some terminology around horses are considered the oldest attested traces of any Indo-Aryan language and it is assumed that they predate the split into Iranian and Indic.

Next steps is Vedic Sankrit, still a lot older than Classic Sanskrit.

Classic Sanskrit is a highly codified and planned language and was created in Northwest India.